# application flow stops at SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing

Tags: iphone, ios

I was implementing in app purchase. Everything is going fine but my flows always stops at SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: Does anybody knows the reason for it?. please help.

```
   - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
  {
NSLog(@"transactions........%@",transactions);
NSLog(@"transactions count........%d",[transactions count]);
NSLog(@"transactions description ........%@",transactions.description);

  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)

    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
             break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"purchasing");
         //   [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"default case");
            break;
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because you're calling:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

By calling this, your app will no longer be notified of additional updates to the transaction. Try to remove this line.

Comment: Sometimes it's better not to remove the observer at all. For example: when user starts a purchase and in the midst of it he's being asked to update his credit card details, he is transferred to the Settings app and after updating successfully he can complete the purchase process outside your app. When coming back to your app, it will receive 2 consecutive transactions, a failed one which is followed by a successful one. In this case you don't want to remove the observer right after the failed transaction and miss the successful one.